# Selenium to scroll through ifinite scrollable pages and scraping data through scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am very new to data scraping and scrapy,I want scrapy to use the page source output which i got using selenium webdriver to scrap data using xpath! Can anybody help me with that. i am getting an error
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'text'

I think i am getting the output in string format and scrapy is not able to covert it. below is the code snippet generating the error.

```
def parse(self, response):
        # process each category link       
    urls = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"colDataInnerBlk")]/p/a/@href').extract()
    for url in urls:
        if len(str(url).strip()) != 0 and url !="javascript:void(0);":
           # absolute_url = response.urljoin(url)
            #request = scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_items)
            self.browser.get(url)
            self.scroll(self.browser)
            while True:
                try:
                    self.find_element(self.browser,By.XPATH,'//div[@id="see-more-products" and @style="visibility: visible;"]')
                    self.click(self.browser,By.XPATH,'//div[@id="see-more-products and @style="visibility: visible;"]')    
                    self.scroll(self.browser)
                except:
                    break
            response=self.browser.page_source
            self.browser.quit()
            time.sleep(2)
            items = DealItem()
            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            items['product_name'] = hxs.select('//p[contains(@class,"product-title") or contains(@class,"pdp-e-i-head")]/text()')
            items['product_sale_price'] = hxs.select('//span[contains(@class,"lfloat product-price") or contains(@class,"payBlkBig") or contains(@class,"pdp-final-price")]/text()')
            items['Mrp_price'] = hxs.select('//span[contains(@class,"lfloat product-desc-price strike")]/text()')
            items['Product_discount'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="product-discount"]/span/text()')
            items['product_category'] = hxs.select('//h1[@class="category-name"]/text()')
            yield items
```

Comment: Post the `Traceback` you are getting.

Comment: On what line is the error occuring?

Comment: i am getting the html response fine but not able to extract from the page_source either by using scray's response.xpath nor by uising hxs.select

Please help me with this.

See the Traceback